# How to have a unique page for each user ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, visual-studio, session

I have in my site a table and I want that each user will get empty table that he can edit by himself and will be displayed for him when he logs in.

For each user the same table but with diffrent values that belong to him and he can edit it.

The edit and the table work fine but the problem is that all the users see the same table with the same values.

Comment: Post your code, it will help folks debug for you.

Comment: Do you mean a rich content editable page? Sounds like a too broad question

Comment: i mean that each user who register to the site will get empty table that he can edit and use by himself. now in my site when user enter they all have the same table with the same values and when one user edit the table the table change for all the users @dalorzo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of creating sessions. You can create a User Row in the UserProfile table of your Database, to save his values.

Then when he's logged in, use his UserId, to create a dynamic URL like

```
www.example.com/userid/1234
```

Stack Overflow uses the very same thing. They use your ID and show you the data related to your own ID. They use Database to store your data of Profile and so on.

The only thing to differ between the table and data would be to use a condition. In SQL it is known as `WHERE` clause, and in coding is known as `if (condition == value) { }`. Use this condition to seperate the values, like this

```
var db = Database.Open("database_name");
var sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE UserId =@0";
var result = db.Query(sqlQuery, WebSecurity.CurrentUserId);
```

This would return only those columns which are related to the user logged in. You can then loop through this result like this

```
foreach (var row in result) {
   // create the table here!
}
```

http://www.asp.net/web-pages/tutorials/data/5-working-with-data

Comment: how can i do it?
maybe you can give me example?
i understood your point but i don't know how to start doing it maybe you can give me some information about it

Comment: Which Language are you using? ASP.NET ?

Comment: yes i am using  asp.net c#

Comment: Use the UserId `WebSecurity.CurrentUserId` as a condition, and then get the table for him from the Database.

Comment: this thing i understood. but how i am using multiple data.
in my site now i have just 1 table that all the users see how i give for each user unique table.

Comment: By using a database and storing the table data for each user in the Database. Alongwith his user id and the table content.

Comment: @Afzaal The code you posted is a bit misleading. Writing an if statement for each user Id in this situation doesn't feel a good approach. The SQL approach you mention is the way to go and future readers of this answer would be better served by an example of that instead.

Comment: @Calvedos, I have editted that and removed the confusion. :) Now it related to SQL version of my answer.